# Loop through all files in a directory and its sub directory using Unix

Tags: unix, hadoop

I have to loop through all files in a directory using Unix and find out the files that are created from a timerange.This is the command I am trying . But somehow that does't list out all files in the directory.

`hadoop fs -ls $a$slash$star |  awk '$6FS$7 >= "2014-12-11 09:00" && $6FS$7 <= "2014-12-12 09:00"''

here `$a` is variable where I have mentioned the directory name.

$slash has /

$start has *

Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that "hadoop fs ..." commands include any globbing directly (that is, * just may not work).

You might try instead:

```
 hadoop fs -ls -R /your/dir/path
```

This should show the list of files under */your/dir/path*. and then you can see if your filtering using awk works (I didn't look at that).

Edit:

On a small cluster I have access to that contains a few thousand files in HDFS, I can run:

```
 $ hadoop fs -ls -R / | awk '$6FS$7 > "2014-07-18 15:30" && $6FS$7 < "2014-07-19 22:00"'
 drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop   supergroup          0 2014-07-18 15:33 /testlog/blah.txt
 -rw-r--r--   2 hadoop   supergroup          0 2014-07-18 15:33 /testlog/blah.txt/_SUCCESS
 -rw-r--r--   2 hadoop   supergroup    5311539 2014-07-18 15:33 /testlog/blah.txt/part-00000
 -rw-r--r--   2 hadoop   supergroup    4400434 2014-07-18 15:33 /testlog/blah.txt/part-00001
```

The filtering and output is similar to the functionality you're after, assuming I understand your question.

Note the **-R** option, and my use of a simple slash character ("/") as the final argument, rather than /your/dir/path: doing the "fs -ls -R /" lists all files in HDFS. I also used different comparison operators in my *awk* expression, but that was to more easily limit results to some nondescript files in this cluster's HDFS content.

Comment: But that is not working . I want to see all files in that directory and the sub directories in that directory which was created on the timerange .